# Fool's Mate - As White?

Tags: checkmate, fools-mate

Fools Mate is simple as black, white opens right up, 2 moves, done.

But if you attempt to do this as white, once you move, black moves, you move, it's only check, there is no checkmate.

Is it possible to get a 2 move checkmate as white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

With two moves as white, you can get out a maximum of one attacker to deliver a check.

With one move as black, there is no weakness you can create that leaves you unable to defend a check from any given attacking vector.